No sound in internal Speakers in Ubuntu 24.04
My configuration is Asus Expertbook D9450FA (Latest firmware installed) and clean installed Ubuntu 24.04 + Windows 11 (Dual boot)
After Installation Ubuntu works correct, but when I boot into Windows once sound in Internal speakers is disappeared. When I'm opening Settings -> Sound I can see Internal Speaker device and when I'm trying to test left and right channels little sound level bar shows that some sound is playing. It looks like all working fine but speaker just is not plugged. If I connect earphones I can hear sound through it when earphone is plugged.
But! after entering BIOS and exit with save changes and exit I can hear sound again. However first boot to Windows breaks all again until I open BIOS.
Looks like my problem is related to this one. Seems like recommended in the topic patch solves the problem but it needs to disable Secure Boot. I want to avoid turning it off. Also here is saying that

THIS IS NOW OBSOLETE WITH KERNEL VERSIONS ≥ 6.7.0

But Ubuntu 24.04 is using kernel version 6.8.0, so I'm not sure if my problem is the same.
Any ideas how to solve the problem? Please feel free to ask if you need more diagnostic information or logs.

Disabling of fast boot in Windows solved my problem. BIOS settings remained untouched.

control panel -> power options -> Choose what the power buttons do -> Change settings that are currently unavailable -> Under 'Shutdown settings,' uncheck the 'Turn on fast startup' box

